# How to create a fake server for Node.js "net"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, server

### Background

I have a use case where my application receives data from a machine every X seconds.

This application connects to that machine via an IP address and a Port, using the [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) official library from Node.js.

```
const net = require("net");
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(config.readerPort, config.readerIP, () => console.log("Connected"));

client.on("close", () => console.log("Connection closed"));

client.on("data", console.log);
```

### Objective

My objective here is to create a fake server that, just like the machine, allows my app to connect to it via an IP and a Port, and that emits events every X seconds as well.

To simulate this I have created a small app that prints 0 every 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(0);
}, 5000);
```

My objective is to, instead of printing to the console, to bind the small app to an IP and a port (localhost) and then make my app read from it.

### Question

Using the `net` library from Node.js (or any other), how do change my fake server from printing to the console to sending that information to the localhost IP and a port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

After much searching, I actually found a way to do this without any external libraries besides `net`.

The result I came to is a variation of this:

```
const net = require('net');

const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = 6969;

net.createServer( sock => {

    console.log(`CONNECTED: ${sock.remoteAddress}:${ sock.remotePort}`);

    sock.on('close',() => console.log("CLOSED"));

    setTimeout(() => {
        sock.write("Hello WOrld\r\n");
    }, 10000);        

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

Then my client machine will happily pick after it.

You can find the original tutorial/source here:

- https://www.hacksparrow.com/tcp-socket-programming-in-node-js.html

### Tips

It is important to watch out with line terminations. According to [node.js socket.write() not work on if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771027/node-js-socket-write-not-work-on-if-condition) if you don't add termination characters like `\r\n`, some clients won't accept them.

Another important consideration may be that you need to force the output put of `write` to be immediate. Read more at [node.js socket.write() not work on if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771027/node-js-socket-write-not-work-on-if-condition).